# How to customize the related videos that appears after the video stops in youtube ?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to control(to show my own list of video) the related video thumbnails that are shown after the video is completed ?

Answer (score 1):

If you create an official "PLAYLIST" on youtube
then you can control the order of max 200 videos.

You simply embed the playlist-code for that list.